# SourceTree - rebase - Errors During Merge

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to do something simple like editing the commit message for a previous commit.

Checking `git status` I have:

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I then click on the commit and do SourceTree > Repository > Interactive Rebase...

but get this dialog box, and a completely blank/empty description area:

[image]

Note: I read somewhere that this might be due to FileMerge creating a .orig backup file. However, looking through FileMerge preferences I don't see anything about backup files

Comment: What does `git status` show after you close that dialog box?

Comment: Nothing. All is as before. I read somewhere that this might be due to FileMerge creating a .orig backup file. However, looking through FileMerge preferences I don't see anything about backup files.

Comment: What happens if you do `git rebase -i` from the command line?

Answer (score 14):

Try in Terminal:

```
git rebase --continue
```

You will see a normal error message.

P.S. `git add .` solved my issue

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that that's not actually how you do an interactive rebase in SourceTree. I know it's a terribly confusing interface... Do *not* choose Sourcetree > Repository > Interactive Rebase. Rather, *Control-click* on the parent commit and choose — from the *contextual menu* — **Rebase children**.

Comment: Seconded. I had that problem too and thought SourceTree is broken, which it not really is (just an interface quirk). Great matt

Answer (score 2):

Branch is not tracked:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<your_branch_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Push a remote version of the branch you want to rebase**

SourceTree is attempting to present you the local commits that have been made on top of the remote branch.

If the remote branch does not exist, SourceTree doesn't know which commit to use as the "parent" of the rebase.

When you get this extremely unhelpful blank error, the issue is that **your current branch does not have a remote**. Or perhaps that your **local branch is up to date with the remote**, and you thus have no commits to rebase.

Push a remote version of your branch *at the commit you want to use as the parent of the rebase.*

Comment: "Little" things like this is why I would only give a lukewarm recommend to SourceTree. It mostly works good enough, but there are these random gotchas. Wouldn't surprise me to find this as a reported unaddressed issue.

Answer (score 1):

check if you have on uncommitted files, can happen as a result of auto-generated files that are under version control

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to **interactive rebase** with **SourceTree** but you get

> **`Errors during merge`**

or SourceTree appears to ***hang*** upon encountering a merge conflict,

this sounds like behaviour attributable to a *identified SourceTree bug*.  (See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2493 and others ending in 2715, 2912)

**A Solution:**

1. **Don't click `Close` on the pop-up message.**
2. **Exit SourceTree**.  For example by right-clicking on the taskbar button and `Close` from there.
3. Open SourceTree.
4. Resolve the conflicts.
5. (Commit changes.)
6. Click `Actions` > `Continue Rebase`.
7. (Repeat this procedure as needed for additional conflicts)

Alternatively, perform steps 4 through 7 with another application or the command line.
Lately I've been enjoying and recommending "Git Fork" client (https://git-fork.com/)