# Sourcetree 4.0.1 for Mac missing UI for interactive rebase

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree

Looking into documentation and other public materials there should be a nice GUI for interactive rebase but instead of it, we have only command line prompt.

[image: Current]

It should look like this

[image: Should be]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312435/341994

Comment: @matt I don't quite understand - "Rebase children of XXX interactively..." from context menu does the same.

Comment: @matt ;) I have Catalina + Sourcetree 4.0.1. Could anyone else confirm the same behaviour?

Comment: I've checked on one previous version the same that my teammate has. It also works on his machine so this bug seems to be environmental.

Comment: Unfortunately not ;)

Comment: Perhaps. Normally, I'm using FileMerge.

Comment: I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to rebase already pushed commits.

Comment: How does that explain anything?

Comment: If you use rebase on not pushed commits it will work as expected.

Comment: But a commit is a commit. Why would the interface magically change just because a commit also exists elsewhere?

Comment: It is rather question to Sourcetree authors - as rebase is not recommended for public branches it probably has been hampered.

Comment: It is not recommended, but nothing prevents doing it. And I do not see what there would be about that situation that would cause the interface to behave differently. As I said, a commit is a commit; it does not magically "know" that it has been shared elsewhere. Please show how this is an _answer_ rather than a further comment contributing to the mystery.

Comment: As I have said I'm not Sourcetree author. The answer explains how it is working - not how it should work. There is a little difference between pushed commit to origin and the not pushed one.

Comment: As I have said, this is not an _answer_. We don't _know_ the answer.